# How to attach a PDF file from Google Drive to attachment array?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have adapted the following snippets of code to try and attach a PDF from Google Drive to an email in Google Scripts.

```
 var optionalAttachmentCell = ss.getSheets()[6].getRange('L2').getValue(); //Here is where the File ID is
 var optionalAttachment = DriveApp.getFileById(optionalAttachmentCell); I believe this should get the file
```

A few lines later I give optionalAttachment[0] as a parameter to my function.

```
 sendSpreadsheetToPdf2(8, shName, ss.getRange('Constants!G25').getValue(), "Pay for the week ending "+date, body, date, driverArray[i],ss.getRange('Constants!G26').getValue(), scheduleBlob, i, Week2Blob, optionalAttachment[0]);
```

I think it goes wrong here

```
if(blob){ //this is a blob that prints out a sheet
  attachmentArray.push(blob); // I attach the sheet to the attachmentArray which starts blank
  if (send1st === true) {  // these are optional spreadsheet blobs I attach
    attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);
  }
  if (send2nd === true) {  // another optional blob
    attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);
  }
  if(optional){
  attachmentArray.push(optional) // This is where I have the opitionalAttachment being put into the array
  }}
```

Then I create a draft using

```
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
 
  if(htmlbody){
  mailOptions.htmlBody = htmlbody;
  }
  
  if(email){
  GmailApp.createDraft(email, subject,"",mailOptions);
```

If possible I would like to keep the attachmentArray as is but just add the optionalAttachment which is a PDF file. I am not sure where it is going wrong; I think it has something to do with the blob/PDF format. Please provide advice. Thank you.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

The advanced parameter `attachments` from [createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) accepts an array of [BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source.html). Therefore, the corresponding `Blob` has to be retrieved, via [File.getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob()).

#### Solution:

I got the PDF to attach by modifying this line:

```
 var optionalAttachment = DriveApp.getFileById(optionalAttachmentCell).getBlob();
```

That way the file a blob like the other blobs I push in the attachment array.

Comment: I edited your answer to clarify what the problem was and fix a typo.